# Purpose of the "system" role in OpenAI chat completions API

Tags: openai, api, chat

I know that the "system" role can be used to set the behavior of the "assistant"
([see here](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api#:%7E:text=The%20system%20message,a%20helpful%20assistant.%22)).

But actually I can also set the "assistant" behavior with a "user" role message.
So why is the "system" role needed?

Comment: This is an interesting question. In an ordinary computer system, it would be to prevent [injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection); but there's no way to defend against those if you're using OpenAI's technology. I'd assume it's just smoke and mirrors, but maybe there's an actual reason for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OpenAI community, there was following [response](https://community.openai.com/t/purpose-of-the-system-role-in-openai-chat-completions-api/497739):

> It’s because newer models are trained to adhere to system messages.
> A system message is never part of the conversation and never accessible to the end-user. Therefore, it can be used to control the scope of the model’s interactions with the end-user.
> The user message can be used to ground the model into a specific behavior, but it cannot control it entirely.
> During the conversation, the user can instruct the model to contradict the statement given by the role user, as they have the same role, and the model cannot deny user asking to override their previous instructions. However, if there’s a system message, the model will give precedence to it over the user message.